# How was the realm door opened in The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

At the beginning of the story in the Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past it says that the door to the realm suddenly opened, giving people access to its mysteries. How did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently part of the GBA intro to the game; the original SNES intro makes mention of sealing the Golden Land, but not the knowledge of how it was opened, just that people sought it and vanished.

All that said, whether considered retcon or just filling in the backstory - **this now refers to the events of Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time**.

In that game, spoilers ahoy:

> Link, as a child, tries to thwart the plans of the thief and dark mage Ganondorf by gaining the treasures that guard the way to the Triforce, planning to find the way himself and defend it.  The way is through the Temple of Time.  Without understanding the entirety of what would happen, he pulls the Master Sword from its pedestal there.  This act opened the gates of the Golden Land, but also sealed Link away until he grew of age and could wield the Master Sword.  This left the way to the Triforce wide open for Ganondorf to claim it, and the rest of the game involves creating the Wise Men's Seal that is broken in the time of A Link to the Past.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using a GBA version, my bad. But this helps.